# Retrieve first few child nodes from Ionic Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is how my database looks:

[image]

I want to fetch only the first 3 nodes such that the last node (here, speakers) is completely ignored.

---

I understand that this can also be implemented using the generic way of fetching all the data and then using Snapshots and iterating with the help of forEach; but I want to do that after fetching only the first 3 child records **[** and not fetch the 4th record at all until explicitly using firebase.database().ref('/signup/') **]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself,

```
public listRef:  firebase.database.Query;
this.listRef =firebase.database().ref('/').limitToFirst(3);
```

Then,

```
this.listRef.on('value', itemSnapshot=> {
          itemSnapshot.forEach( itemSnap => {

            //Your code
            });
      })
```

This fetches only the first 3 child nodes. Similarly, *limitToLast(n)* will display the last *n* child nodes

---

For further reading:
[Querying in Angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md)